# Reading data into an array and printing it

Tags: arrays, c

I have just started learning how to program and I came across an assignment whereby I have to create an array wherein the weight of the elephant seals is read & printed. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code, because I can read in the data but my data is being printed wrong when I call the printArray function.
Below is my code:

```
/* 
compute the weight average of elephant seals using an array that will read in the data 
*/

#include <stdio.h>

void arrayReadingData(const int sizeP) //array to read in the weight of the elephantseals
{
    
    int weightP[sizeP];
    for(int i = 1; i <= sizeP; i++)
    {
        printf("Elephant seal %d weight is: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &weightP[i]);
    }
}

void printArray(const int sizeP)
{
    
    int weightP[sizeP];
    for(int i = 1; i <= sizeP; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", weightP[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    
    int size;
    printf("How many seals do you want to calculate the average weight for: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    arrayReadingData(size);
    printArray(size);
};
```

Comment: `int weightP[sizeP];` defines a ***local*** variable `weightP`. The life-time of this variable will end when the function ends. You better take up your text-books and read more about scopes, life-time, and how to pass arguments to functions.

Comment: Also remember what your text-books say about array indexes, and how they start from *zero* and not one.

Comment: ...and how C arrays are indexed from zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the for loop wrong, your loop should start at i = 0 to i < sizeP, when i = sizeP weights[sizeP] will be assigned an arbitrary value.

Update:
I just noticed you are declaring the array as a local variable to each function and declaring it the wrong way, you should declare that array in the main function and pass it to your functions instead

Here is a solution you can use

```
/* 
compute the weight average of elephant seals using an array that will read in the data 
*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 3

void arrayReadingData(int weightP[]) //array to read in the weight of the elephantseals
{
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Elephant seal %d weight is: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &weightP[i]);
    }
}

void printArray(int weightP[])
{
    
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", weightP[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    
    int weights[SIZE];

    arrayReadingData(weights);
    printArray(weights);
};
```

Note: if you want the size to be given by the user you can use pointers and allocate memory dynamically

Here is how you can achieve that:

```
/* 
compute the weight average of elephant seals using an array that will read in the data 
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void arrayReadingData(int weightP[], int size) //array to read in the weight of the elephantseals
{
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Elephant seal %d weight is: \n", i);
        scanf("%d", &weightP[i]);
    }
}

void printArray(int weightP[], int size)
{
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", weightP[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    
    int* weightsArray;
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of the array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    weightsArray = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    
    if(weightsArray == NULL){
        printf("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    arrayReadingData(weightsArray, size);
    printArray(weightsArray, size);
    
    free(weightsArray);
};
```

Comment: I have put both the size and array as parameters of the function, but now I can only read and print 10 numbers, more than 10 i get an error stating: "ZSH: Segmentation fault"

Comment: As I pointed out, if you want your array size to be dynamic(i.e. pass in different sizes at run time) you should use a pointer and allocate memory for it dynamically (you can use malloc) , I have updated my answer check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I redid the code, after learning from the comments and I came up with this solution, the problem is that now I can only read in 10 numbers and print 10 numbers if I read in 11 numbers and try to print it I get an error stating **zsh: segmentation fault**

/*
compute the weight average of elephant seals using an array that will read in the data
*/

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrayReadingData(const int sizeP, int weightP[]) //array to read in the weight of the elephant seals
{
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeP; i++)
    {
        printf("Elephant seal %d weight is: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &weightP[i]);
    }
}

void printArray(const int sizeP, int weightP[])
{
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeP; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", weightP[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    
    int size;
    int weight[size];
    printf("How many seals do you want to calculate theaverage weightfor:");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    arrayReadingData(size, weight);
    printArray(size, weight);
}
```